# Angular 2 router reloading component

Tags: angular, routes

I am having problems with what looks to be the Angular router reloading the component in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and causing undesired results. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/yRCzbsxE0ftzqrDeRT69?p=preview

How can I change it so the variable isn't reinitialized when alternating between link 'one' and 'two'

Comment: Save it in a service and fetch it from there every time you navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **shared service** and inject it to Parent, that service can have `getter` and `setter` and you can share the data from there... something like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  public data:any;

  setData(value:any) {
    this.data = value
  }

  getData():any {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

and provide in a parent, for example app.module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AnotherComponent,
    SecondComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ MyService ], //<< add it in providers section and access it inside your component...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```